# Wunused-but-set-variable warning treatment

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

I have the following code, and while compiling it with gcc-4.6 I get warning:

> warning: variable ‘status’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]

```
#if defined (_DEBUG_)
#define ASSERT       assert
#else                           /* _DEBUG_ */
#define ASSERT( __exp__ )
#endif   

static inline void cl_plock(cl_plock_t * const p_lock)
{
        status_t status;
        ASSERT(p_lock);
        ASSERT(p_lock->state == INITIALIZED);

        status = pthread_rwlock_unlock(&p_lock->lock);
        ASSERT(status == 0); 
}
```

When  _DEBUG_
flag isn't set I get the warning.
Any ideas how can I workaround this warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your `ASSERT` macro to:

```
#if defined (_DEBUG_)
#define ASSERT       assert
#else                           /* _DEBUG_ */
#define ASSERT( exp ) ((void)(exp))
#endif
```

If the expression has no sideeffects, then it should still be optimised out, but it should also suppress the warning (if the expression *does* have side-effects, then you would get different results in debug and non-debug builds, which you don't want either!).

Comment: What do you mean by side-effects?

Comment: @alnet: An expression with side-effects is one that changes something - for example, `ASSERT(i++);`.

Comment: I have related issue right now :) [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641538/has-no-member-compilation-error)

Comment: Unfortunately, /usr/include/assert.h (on my platform at least) defines `assert(exp) ((void)0)`, which means that `exp` is discarded and you still get the warning.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler option to turn off unused variable warnings is `-Wno-unused`.
To get the same effect on a more granular level you can use [diagnostic pragmas](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html) like this:

```
int main()
{
  #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-variable"
  int a;
  #pragma GCC diagnostic pop
  // -Wunused-variable is on again
  return 0;
}
```

This is, of course, not portable but you can use [something similar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for VS.

Comment: If you were going to do this then you could just use the `__attribute__((unused))` annotation on the declaration.

Answer (score 1):

You could surround the variable declaration of `status` with a `#ifdef` clause.

```
#ifdef _DEBUG_
    status_t status
#endif
```

**EDIT:** You have to surround the call also:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG_
    status = pthread_rwlock_unlock(&p_lock->lock);
#else
    pthread_rwlock_unlock(&p_lock->lock);
#endif
```

or you can switch off the error message.