# has no member compilation error

Tags: c, linux, gcc, gcc-warning

I have the following code and when I'm trying to compile it, I get an error:

> error: ‘list_item_t’ has no member named ‘state’

Any creative ideas how to make this piece of code compile without warnings and erros?

```
 #if defined (_DEBUG_)
 #define ASSERT       assert
 #else                           /* _DEBUG_ */
 #define ASSERT( exp ) ((void)(exp))
 #endif`

typedef struct list_item {
        struct list_item *p_next;
        struct list_item *p_prev;
 #ifdef _DEBUG_
        int state;
 #endif
 } list_item_t;

main(int argc, char *argv)
{
    list_item_t p_list_item;

    ASSERT(p_list_item.state == 0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just `#define` `ASSERT` as

```
 #if defined (_DEBUG_)
 #define ASSERT       assert
 #else                          
 #define ASSERT( exp ) (void)0
 #endif
```

Note that this may change the behaviour of other code spots because `ASSERT` no longer evaluates its argument, but that's how people expect it to behave anyway.

Or perform a `_DEBUG_` build, but this doesn't resolve the problem, it just avoids it.

Comment: When doing so, I get `warning: unused variable ‘p_list_item’ [-Wunused-variable]`

Comment: Because you didn't use it then - you can solve it by putting another `_DEBUG_` guard around the declaration of `p_list_item`.

Comment: @ainet That's expected, your code makes no use of p_list_item unless \_DEBUG\_ is defined. You can't do anything about that by just changing the ASSERT macros.

Answer (score 2):

Your class has the mentioned member if and only if  `_DEBUG_` is defined, and it apparently isn't.

`#define _DEBUG_`

in the beginning of your TU or change project settings to define it in some other way

Comment: You are right. This should compile with _DEBUG_ set and without it. The problem I experience is when _DEBUG_ isn't set.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to

```
#define ASSERT( exp ) ((void)(exp))
```

which evaluates `p_list_item.state == 0` and thus needs `state` to exist even when `_DEBUG_` is not `#define`'d.

Comment: I want this code to compile for both cases when _DEFINE_=1 and when _DEFINE_=0

Comment: @alnet: then you should either put in the `state` member unconditionally, or only use `ASSERT` inside an `#ifdef _DEBUG_` block. Note, btw., that you should not define macros starting with `_` and a capital letter; such names are reserved for internal use by the C implementation.