# warning: variable set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

I have been getting following warning while compiling the C source code in the `gcc 4.6.1`.

```
   warning: variable set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
```

I refered to this link [Wunused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583237/wunused-but-set-variable-warning-treatment) but could get exactly what is causing this warning.Would anybody tell me in more details what is causing this warning and how can We get rid of it?

[EDIT]
 I have a following snippet of code. The compile shows the above mentioned warning. Could you please suggest me how can correct it?

```
   test_function(){
   BOOL BoolTest;
   BoolTest = test_fucntion2();

   #ifdef CHECK
   if (!BoolTest) {
   misc_StartErrorReport();
   misc_ErrorReport("\n test_function2: Input not indexed.\n");
   misc_FinishErrorReport();
          }
   #endif
   // 
    BoolTest is no more used below it.
   // }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to include the preprocessor guards around the declaration and initialisation of `BoolTest`:

```
test_function()
{
#ifdef CHECK
    BOOL BoolTest = test_function2();
#else
    test_function2();
#endif


#ifdef CHECK
    if (!BoolTest) {
        misc_StartErrorReport();
        misc_ErrorReport("\n test_function2: Input not indexed.\n");
        misc_FinishErrorReport();
    }
#endif
```

(this assumes that you still want to call `test_function2()` even if `CHECK` is not defined, presumably for its side-effects - if not, then you don't need the `#else` section and you can combine the two `#ifdef` blocks into one).

Answer (score 5):

Setting a variable is assigning it a value (maybe implicitly)

```
int main(void) {
    int local1, local2;
    local1 = 0; /* local1 set to 0 */
    local2 = 0; /* local2 set to 0 */
    return 0;
}
```

In the program above, both variables were set to a value but they weren't used.
If I replace the second line with

```
    int local2 = local1;
```

now I have used the `local1` variable -- and the warnings should be only 1.

To get rid of the warning, delete the assignment from your code. This may, in turn create other warnings ... :)

Answer (score 4):

With g++ 7.x and higher and clang++ 4.x and higher (using c++11 or higher),
as well as with Visual Studio 2017 version 15.3 and later (available with /std:c++17), you can use the standarized [[maybe_unused]] attribute.

For example,

```
int main()
{
    int x [[maybe_unused]] = 5;
}
```

will not give a warning, not even with -Wunused-variable and the likes.

Comment: probably worth remarking (since the question was about C), that C23 has standarized this as well, so this code will likely also work without warnings (even if `-pedantic -Wpedantic` is used) also in recent gcc/clang by using the `-std=c2x` or equivalent flag.

Answer (score 3):

It means that you assign a value to a variable, but then you never read that value later in your code (hence the verbage, "set but not used"). For example:

```
int useful = 10;
int useless = 3;
if (useful) {
    //Do stuff
}
```

Notice that you give both `useful` and `useless` values, but you only read the value in `useful`.
Usually, when I get this message it means that I forgot about a variable or found a way to inline a statement that no longer needs that variable.

Answer (score 2):

https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/porting_to.html

> New warnings for unused variables and parameters
>
> The behavior of -Wall has changed and now includes the new warning
> flags -Wunused-but-set-variable and (with -Wall -Wextra)
> -Wunused-but-set-parameter. This may result in new warnings in code that compiled cleanly with previous versions of GCC.
>
> For example,
>
> void fn (void)   {
> int foo;
> foo = bar ();  /* foo is never used.  */   }
>
> Gives the following diagnostic:
>
> warning: variable "foo" set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
>
> Although these warnings will not result in compilation failure, often
> -Wall is used in conjunction with -Werror and as a result, new warnings are turned into new errors.
>
> To fix, first see if the unused variable or parameter can be removed
> without changing the result or logic of the surrounding code. If not,
> annotate it with `__attribute__((__unused__))`.
>
> As a workaround, add -Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable or
> -Wno-error=unused-but-set-parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You have not used BoolTest. You can see there is no difference between your code and

```
test_function(){
#ifdef CHECK
if (!test_fucntion2()) {
```